# How to strike the right balance between memory usage and time efficiency in Python: vectorisation is faster but memory demanding

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, memory, vectorization

I am attending a course of machine learning. I was asked to train a perceptron on 300 samples (which are float arrays long 20) for 1000 times.
This gives you the idea of how a single training works:

```
import numpy as np

train_set=np.random.randint(0,2,size=(300,20))*2-1 #my train data are arrays made of -1 and 1
true_classification=train_set@teacher_weights    #teacher_perceptron is the array to which the student 
                                                 #will have to tend to. The classification 
                                                 #is made via a simple matrix product.
student_weights=np.random.normal(0,1,size=20) #this initialises the perceptron to a rd array
epsilon=1 #this will be the fraction of classification errors made by the student
while epsilon>0:
   epsilon=0
   student_classification=train_set@student_weights
   for i in range(300):
      if true_classification[i]!=student_classification[i]:
         student_weights+= {... some update rule, unimportant}
         epsilon+=1
   epsilon/=300
```

In my code I actually put this in a `learning` function, this is just to show you the problem. If I try to iterate it 1000 times with a `for` loop it takes me ages. Being a novice of Python, I just learned that loops are its weak point. To exploit Python's goodness at matrix multiplication I should maybe store the samples in a 20x300x1000 array, but then memory issues pop up. How can I find the right balance between memory usage and time efficiency?

Comment: Just for terminology's sake, that's not a 20-dimensional array.  The samples are a vector (1-dimensional array) with 20 elements.

Comment: You should be able to vectorize that inner `for` loop using numpy techniques without totally rearranging your data.  `true_classification != student_classification` returns a boolean array you can use to do further vector operations.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's usually a good compromise to keep the active dataset size within a loop somewhere between level 2 and level 3 cache size. So maybe 64 kiB to a few megabytes at most. That's large enough that the interpreter overhead is drowned out and small enough to not choke on main memory bandwidth, especially when parallelized. For GPUs things are different